# Trying to setup Memcached with Symfony running on NGINX/HHVM

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, memcached, hhvm

I have memcached installed and working as tested by:

```
nc -U /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock
stats
STAT pid 16360
STAT uptime 2246
STAT time 1412217254
STAT version 1.4.14 (Ubuntu)
STAT libevent 2.0.21-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 0.032563
//and so on...
```

The problem i have is that when symfony loads and invokes session_start() it throws an error:

> Fatal error: Failed to initialize storage module: 
>   user (path: /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock) in /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php on line 147

I have tried to configure session.save_path tons of different ways always with the same error just with the path different:

```
session.save_path = "/var/run/memcached/memcached.sock"
session.save_path = "unix:/var/run/memcached/memcached.sock"
session.save_path = "unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached.sock"
session.save_path = /var/run/memcached/memcached.sock
session.save_path = unix:/var/run/memcached/memcached.sock
session.save_path = unix:///var/run/memcached/memcached.sock
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why i am unable to start the session?

**Version Info:**

```
Ubuntu: 14.04.1
NGINX: 1.4.6
HHVM-nightly: 3.4.0-dev+2014.10.01
memcached: 1.4.14
symfony: 2.5.5
```

**UPDATE** 
I have been digging around and trying different configs. If i run symfony using apache/php5.5.17 configured with the following session parameters it works:

```
session.handler_name: memcached
session.save_path = "127..0.0.1:11211"
```

I have also tried this config with nginx/hhvm and i still get the same error.

Comment: Which specific version of Symfony are you using? (the version tag # or commit id)

Comment: i am using version 2.5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because HHVM does not have an inbuilt memcache[d] session handler. It only comes with Redis and file ones.

You can either use one of those backends, or implement your own using [SessionHandlerInterface](http://php.net/SessionHandlerInterface) and [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler)

Comment: I found another link that had the memcached class and service config i needed to get it working. Thanks

Comment: could you please share how you did it? I am facing the same problem. Thanks